# Using scan in reactive statement

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to write a simple program in R using Shiny. The program reads a text files selected by the user, and then displays this as an .html object. I'm using the 'scan' function to read the text file (NB currently only trying to output the first line). The program runs, but the output is not updated. Why isn't the output being updated? Thanks.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(

  ui <- fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput("text_file", "Choose text file",
                    multiple = FALSE,
                    accept = c(".txt")
          )
        ),
        mainPanel(htmlOutput("example"))
      )
    ), 

  server <- function(input, output, session){

    text <- reactive({
            req(input$text_file)
            x <- scan(input$text_file, what = "string", sep = "\n")[1]
            })
    # text output
    output$example <- reactive({
        renderUI({
          HTML(x)
          })
    })
  }
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some changes you need to make:

1. File reading a file, you have to ask the file to be read from `input$inputId$datapath` and not `input$inputId`.
2. Your `renderUI()` should return `text()` and not `x`, as `text()` is your reactive object being rendered.
3. You do not need to add `reactive()` to any `render` functions in shiny as they are already reactive.

Change your server to the following:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

  text <- reactive({
    req(input$text_file)
    x <- scan(input$text_file$datapath, what = "string", sep = "\n")[1]
  })

  # text output
  output$example <- renderUI({
      HTML(text())
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly. And thanks for explanations of key concepts.